# Single Select Mechanism

Tags: interaction-design, dropdown, radio-buttons, combobox

Are there any mechanisms for single select besides radio buttons and dropdown menus (combo boxes)?

Here's an image of the layout I'm designing: [image: radio button selection]

Users can only single select a product, and the feedback was that the radio button was boring. I want to see if there's any other single select mechanism I can use in this layout. Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why don't the established controls that you mention fit your use case?

Comment: It heavily depends on the use case. What is the situation you want to use it for? Are we talking about a form? Or is it part of landing page content? What's the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

How about using button groups?

Something like this:
[image: Button row]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the platform.

Some platforms offer single selection list boxes.  These look like multiple selection list boxes, except that when you click on an item, your previous selection is cleared cleared before your current selection is highlighted.

[Here's a rough example](https://jsfiddle.net/ydbk248f/embedded/result/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you share an example of what you described?

Comment: @Julia I edited the answer to include a link to an example.